# Unity Gaze Input for GearVR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gear-vr

Okay, so, I got the challenge to create a program, in Unity for GearVR. 
I have to make a program which makes use of gaze input, so if you stare at an object for several seconds it'll display you a 360* video.

I barely can't find any GearVR Gaze Input tutorials around on the web so I wanted to give it a shot on Stackoverflow, and hopefully someone could help me out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [Physics.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html). This method emits a ray from the camera point to the camera orientation. You can use something like that:

```
// Does the Ray hit an object with a component named MyObjectScript?
RaycastHit hit;
Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit) )
{
    var script = hit.transform.GetComponent<MyObjectScript>();
    if (script != null)
    {
        //Do your stuff...
    }
}
```

Simply put this script on your camera in the `FixedUpdate` method and another script named `MyObjectScript` in the object you want to detect.